# 2nd order partial differential equation with non-constant coefficients

Tags: differential-equations

During my research I came across the following differential equation:
$$f(x,y) = \left(y^2 \partial_{x}^{2} + x^2 \partial_{y}^{2} \right)f(x,y)$$
Any ideas how to solve it without using series expansion method - just close form expression?

Comment: Since your unknown function seems to be $f$, this is a **linear** equation, though with non-constant coefficients.

Comment: Sorry for that. I corrected the topic.

Comment: @R. Bryant : I think that the change of variable leads to a more complicated equation, which includes some irst-order derivatives. Perhaps you should put a weight in $g$.

Comment: @RobertBryant I can't see you equation by changing the variables. I also get first order derivatives.

Comment: @DenisSerre:  Oh, yes, you are right.  I forgot about the first derivatives and the need for a scaling factor.  Give me a few minutes, and I'll put in a correction.

Comment: @Nex_Friedrich what kind of closed form do you expect? Say what would it look like for a more simple equation $f=\Delta f$?

Comment: OK.  Here's the right substitution:  $x = \sqrt{u}$, $y=\sqrt{v}$ and $h(u,v)={(uv)^{1/4}}f(\sqrt{u},\sqrt{v})$.  Then the equation becomes $$h_{uu}+h_{vv} +\left(\frac{3u^2-4uv+3v^2}{16u^2v^2}\right)h = 0.$$ Now you can apply Darboux' Method to determine whether there is an exact integral and, if there isn't, you can try finding a kernel representation or separation of variables.

Comment: @Andrew:  Actually, a better example is the equation $h_{uu}+h_{vv}=(2/v^2)h$, which has the general solution $$h(u,v) = \frac{\mathrm{Im}\bigl(f(u{+}iv)\bigr)}{v} - \mathrm{Re}\bigl(f'(u{+}iv)\bigr),$$ where $f$ is a holomorphic function of its argument.  The equation $h_{uu}+h_{vv}  = h$ doesn't have such a closed form solution, it's true (which is an old theorem of Sophus Lie), but Darboux' Method is precisely tuned to determine whether $h_{uu}+h_{vv} = g(u,v) h$ has a closed form solution (as in the above example) for a given function $g(u,v)$.

Comment: @RobertBryant great job! Unfortunately I don't know about Darboux method :(

Comment: @Nex_Friedrich: Well, Darboux' Method is a long shot anyway, so unless you really need this, it might be more trouble than it's worth.  There is one further transformation that you can do, though, that you might find useful.  If you make the exponential coordinate change $u+iv=r\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}$, then the above equation becomes $$h_{rr}+h_{\theta\theta}+\left(\frac{3-2\sin 2\theta}{4\sin^2 2\theta}\right)h=0,$$ which displays the maximum symmetry of the equation, i.e., the translation invariance under $r$ (with $0<\theta<\pi/2$, of course). This could be useful for separation of variables.

Comment: @RobertBryant I am worried that at the end I will end up with some infinite series using separation of variables. I wanted to avoid this. The above problem came from generating function $f(x,y) = \sum\limits_{n,m}x^{n}y^{m}c_{n,m}$ for coefficients $c_{n,m}$, so that is why I am looking for solution (if exists) that is not represented by the series.

Comment: @Nex_Friedrich:  It sounds as though you are looking for a particular solution, not the general solution. Do you know anything more about your function than that it satisfies the given second-order linear equation?  For example, do you know a domain of convergence of the power series solution that you already have written down?

Comment: @Nex_Friedrich:  So is it true that you are looking for a solution $f$ of your original equation that *has* an expansion as a power series in $x$ and $y$ (even though you don't want it expressed in that form)?  Isn't the only such solution $f(x,y) = 0$?

Comment: @RobertBryant I ma sorry, but checked my notes and spotted a really stupid mistake. Initially differential equation looked like this: $\partial_{t}\Gamma(x,y,t) = (y^2 \partial_{x}^2 + x^2 \partial_{y}^2)\Gamma(x,y,t)$, but I blindly separated time. We could assume then initial condition $\Gamma(x,y,0) = g(x,y)$, but now it is a different story...

Comment: @Nex_Friedrich:  Ah, that makes more sense.  Are you still looking for solutions $\Gamma(x,y,t)$ that *have* a power series expansion in $(x,y,t)$ in a neighborhood of the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$?  (I understand that you would like a 'closed form' of the solution with a given $g(x,y)$ as $\Gamma(x,y,0)$.)

Comment: @RobertBryant Yes I am still interested in solution for $\Gamma(x,y,t)$, but maybe I will open a new question and describe where does this equation comes from. Thank you for your help !